# override django admin template doesnot work

Tags: python, django-admin

I do exactly ad in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates, but no success yes. This is templates directory structure.

```
templates
    |--admin
          |--news
               |--article
                    |-- index.html
```

index.html i copied from django.contrib.admin.templates.admin ->index.html and modified after.

there is no any changes it is still using original from django package

if i will copy index.html to templates-> admin -> index.html
then it is replaced and it is for all applications. But refuse to change for certain app.

Comment: In your last paragraph, you mean you copied "index.html" to **your** `templates/admin/` directory? Or to `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin`?

Comment: from django/contrib/admin/templates/admin to $PROJECT_HOME/templates/admin/news/article/

Comment: You say: "if i will copy index.html to templates-> admin -> index.html then...". Does this mean copy to `$PROJECT_HOME/templates/admin/index.html`?

Comment: if i will copy index.html to $PROJECT_HOME/templates/admin/index.html when it works as expected, admin template for all my apps changed.

Comment: if i will copy index.html to $PROJECT_HOME/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/index.html when nothing happening

Comment: Shouldn't the file be change_list.html? index.html is meant just for the main admin page.

Comment: that is true. how did i miss it.